# Error on & after 13th of Every Month; When Converting Date and/or Time from character string

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

The code below Works ok; from 01st to 12th of every month; However as soon as I click on 13th or greater date I Get this error

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

This my Code

```
 DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    myConnection.Open();
    string cmdStr1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Payment WHERE PaymentDate = '" + dt + "'";
    SqlCommand PIDexist1 = new SqlCommand(cmdStr1, myConnection);
    int temp1 = Convert.ToInt32(PIDexist1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    myConnection.Close();
```

Thank for your Help

This is How Date is saved in my Database `2012-01-13`

Comment: Going to guess your database is not configured for that date format. So when you select 13 or higher it thinks month instead of day. What flavor of database are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, never bind dates like that. Let the .NET data provider handle this for you - there are just way too many pitfalls with locales on the App and Sql Server for you to use strings as dates.

```
myConnection.Open();
string cmdStr1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Payment WHERE PaymentDate = @dt'";
SqlCommand PIDexist1 = new SqlCommand(cmdStr1, myConnection);
SqlParameter parameter = PIDexist1.Parameters.Add("@dt", System.Data.SqlDbType.DateTime);
parameter.Value = dt;
...
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it's trying to convert 13 as the month.

Try using `DateTime.Parse("...", [Culture])` and specifying the appropriate culture.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you're encountering a `DD-MM-YY` vs `MM-DD-YY` situation. It's too much of a coincidence that it works until the 12th day when there are 12 months. Try to be more explicit in your use of dates; perhaps use the three letter month code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert the date .ToString(). Simply use the SelectedDate DateTime value as named parameter to the SqlCommand query. If you need the day only, use the DateTime.Date property